# Problems with bootable usb stick

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, uefi, bios

First i would like to say i am no expert so i will try to explain as good as i could.

My system is ubuntu only but i have to install Windows in order to use Keil for a group project. I created a bootable usb but it does not work. Here are some details that might help.

Edit: I am not trying to make a system on my usb , I want to have a dual boot system. I was going to install the windows on a different partition.

- I downloaded the iso from my uni servers , probably not an iso problem.
- Tried to use it on my friend's pc , it did not work on his laptop too , but in windows when setup is pressed (while system is up) windows 7 setup starts. so i do not think the problem is with iso (again).
- USB is flagged boot and boot only.
- I thought there might be a problem with the usb stick itself so bought a new one , still does not work.
- I had windows on my computer 6-7 months ago and there are still it's "ashes" in the mbr.
- BIOS does not see the usb.
- Grub does not see the usb.
- I used rufus with these configs: MBR Partition Scheme for BIOS or UEFI-CSM , NTFS , 4096 bytes.

Comment: As far as I know, there are very very limited options for a live-bootable Windows environment. I looked into this at one point and the only option I could find was so limited that it was basically useless. You just can't do what you are able to do with Ubuntu (boot into the OS on any machine and do stuff). Sounds like you either need to set up dual boot (which is no walk in the park) or set up a VM within which you can run Windows. I would recommend the latter.

Comment: I guess i should have said it before. I am trying to make a dual boot system.

Comment: I saw that post earlier. And just to make sure i created the usb with my friends laptop (which is windows).

Comment: UEFI boot requires FAT32 with boot flag, not NTFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question does not clearly state if you are trying (1) to run Windows on a stick as a "live" image where no data is installed on your hard drive or (2) trying to install a dual-boot system.

If you are in situation (1), support for Windows as a "live" version (which is called *Windows To Go* in Microsoft terminology) started with Windows 8 and it could explain why trying to install a Windows 7 version this way does not work. [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) tool and [that link](http://www.intowindows.com/rufus-to-create-windows-to-go-usb-drive/) could help you create a bootable and live USB stick for ulterior Windows version though.

If you are in situation (2), it might be related to UEFI boot issues. In that case, you could try reinstall the ISO image on your USB stick with [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) using GPT partitioning for the stick and UEFI boot.

Hope this helps !

Comment: I forgot to mention it , i edited my question now. I am not trying to make a windows to go. I am trying to install windows in another partition of my ssd. So dual boot

Comment: @pmurdy I have reinstalled it 3 times. All with slow wipes. This might sound stupid but what you meant by "UEFI boot" ?

Comment: When you use Rufus to create your bootable USB drive, you can choose which _partition scheme_ you want to use. There you can choose `GPT for UEFI boot` (which is required if you have secure boot option in your BIOS). Does that make sense to you ?

Comment: Good luck with that ! I just edited the answer to reflect our discussion and make things clearer.

Comment: update. Tried what you did. This time i could see my usb in bios. I chose it as primary boot option. I got this problem however https://ibb.co/jiSDb7

Comment: This might indicate that Windows keys are stored on your hard-drive (for instance if you bought your computer with Windows pre-installed). There might be an option in your BIOS to modify the content of the UEFI boot partition but this is another story...

Comment: If it solved the *original* problem, could you please accept the answer ? Thanks !

Comment: No matter what i tried i could not solve it. I even tried to get tech support from various places. Eventually i just used a WM. Thank you